# this bundle is invalid the key required device in info.plist

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, ios-universal-app

I recently removed the universal compatibility of my app making it iPad only. And uploaded the binary (with an updated version). But  shows the following error

This bundle does not support one or more of the devices that were supported in the previous bundle for this app. Bundles must continue to support any devices previously supported

Is there any possible solution for it. Please help.

[image]

Comment: I can't find the documentation to prove it, but I don't think you can reduce your compatibility unless you make a new app.

Comment: However, can you post a screenshot of the error as I'm having difficulty reading that error message with the formatting

Comment: Btw. You can do a screenshot by typing Cmd+Shift+4 and dragging a box.

Comment: To get a screenshot of a specific window : Cmd+Shift+4 then hit space bar with the mouse place on the window you want to get a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the fourth error carefully.. that's the proof I was looking for in my first comment:

> Your app update must continue to support all devices previously supported.